# Ajax: return all but first array for a key from json

Tags: jquery, ajax

In the example below (may not be valid; I've snipped a lot of information out of this json to avoid confusion), I'm trying to access all of the information in the "roles" array with the exception of the FIRST set of roles data:

```
 {
    "last_name": "Beyor",
    "roles": [
    {
        "term": "2013-2014",
        "end_date": null,
        "district": "Franklin-5",
        "other_parties": [],
        "chamber": "lower",
        "state": "vt",
        "party": "Republican",
        "type": "member",
        "start_date": null
    },
    {
        "term": "2013-2014",
        "committee_id": "VTC000018",
        "chamber": "lower",
        "state": "vt",
        "subcommittee": null,
        "committee": "Fish, Wildlife And Water Resources",
        "position": "ranking member",
        "type": "committee member"
        }
    ],
}
```

This correctly gets all ROLES data, but the way this API is formatted, I don't need the first set of data.  Is there an easy way to exclude it from the function below?

```
   var roles = json.roles;
  if (roles.length != 0) {

 $(".roles").html('<strong>Committeees</strong>');

$.each(roles, function(i, q) {
 $(".roles").append('<br />Term: '+q.term +'<br />Committee: '+q.committee+'<br />Subcommittee: '+q.subcommittee+'<br />Position: '+q.member+'<br />Type: '+q.type+'<br /><br />');
});
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) the first item off:

```
var roles = json.roles.slice(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [`.shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift):

```
json.roles.shift(); // remove first item from the array
```

You can now use:

```
var roles = json.roles;
if ( roles.length ) {
    // Wuhuu roles.length > 0
```